# Change menu options order

Tags: routes, nodes

I am a beginner with Drupal. I have successfully installed it and:

1. Created the front page. I did it through Content, Add content, Basic page. Then Configuration, Site information and then in the Default front page I put the alias of my Basic page.
2. Created an Image gallery with ColoxBox plugin. I went to Structure, Views and created a new view. This view is linked to the Main menu in order to obtain a link in the Menu.

The problem is that my Galleries link came before the Home link.

How can I change the order of these links?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu (drupal 7) You can drag the menus to set the order. Or give then weight.